GRU_cell incompatible shapes TensorFlow
While training my DQN agent in Python3, I carry out forward passes in my GNN created with TensorFlow 2.9.0 and Keras. It always runs correctly, but sometimes, at some point, I get the following error:
Exception encountered when calling layer "my_model" (type myModel).

Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'gru_cell/add_7' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/.conda/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/.conda/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/Users/arnauem/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
      cli.main()
    File "/Users/arnauem/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
      run()
    File "/Users/arnauem/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 284, in run_file
      runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
    File "/Users/arnauem/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
      return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
    File "/Users/arnauem/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
      _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
    File "/Users/arnauem/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/DQN/train_DQN.py", line 408, in <module>
      action = agent.act(env_eval, state, True)
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/DQN/train_DQN.py", line 197, in act
      self.listQValues = self.primary_network(node_states,
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/.conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/.conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 490, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/.conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/.conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/.conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/DQN/mpnn.py", line 88, in call
      for _ in range(self.hparams['T']):
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/DQN/mpnn.py", line 136, in call
      outputs, node_state_list = self.Update(nodes_inputs, [node_hidden_states])
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/.conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/.conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1014, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/.conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/arnauem/Documents/tfg/DRL-GNN/.conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/rnn/gru.py", line 313, in call
      h = z * h_tm1 + (1 - z) * hh
Node: 'gru_cell/add_7'
Incompatible shapes: [176,4] vs. [0]
     [[{{node gru_cell/add_7}}]] [Op:__inference_call_1229]

The code of my neural network is the following:

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import regularizers
import numpy as np

#hparams['node_state_dim']
#hparams['link_state_dim']

class myModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, hparams):
        super(myModel, self).__init__()
        self.hparams = hparams

        # Define layers here
        #Message function
        self.Message = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        self.Message.add(keras.layers.Dense(2*self.hparams['node_state_dim'] + self.hparams['link_state_dim'],
                                            activation=tf.nn.selu, name="FirstLayer"))
        self.Message.add(keras.layers.Dense(2*self.hparams['node_state_dim'] + self.hparams['link_state_dim'],
                                            activation=tf.nn.selu, name="SecondLayer"))
        self.Message.add(keras.layers.Dense(self.hparams['node_state_dim'],
                                            activation=tf.nn.selu, name="ThirdLayer"))

        #Update function
        self.Update = tf.keras.layers.GRUCell(self.hparams['node_state_dim'], dtype=tf.float32)

        #Readout function
        self.Readout = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        self.Readout.add(keras.layers.Dense(self.hparams['readout_units'],
                                            activation=tf.nn.selu,
                                            kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(hparams['l2']),
                                            name="Readout1"))
        self.Readout.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=hparams['dropout_rate']))
        self.Readout.add(keras.layers.Dense(self.hparams['readout_units'],
                                            activation=tf.nn.selu,
                                            kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(hparams['l2']),
                                            name="Readout2"))
        self.Readout.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=hparams['dropout_rate']))
        self.Readout.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(hparams['l2']),
                                            name="Readout3"))

    def build(self, input_shape=None):
        #Tensor shape = (batch_size, input_size)
        self.Message.build(input_shape=tf.TensorShape([None, 2*self.hparams['node_state_dim'] + self.hparams['link_state_dim']]))
        self.Update.build(input_shape=tf.TensorShape([None,self.hparams['node_state_dim']]))
        self.Readout.build(input_shape=[None, self.hparams['node_state_dim']])
        self.built = True
    
    
    #indices is a 1d tensor
    #index_size is the number of different values that each index can have
    @staticmethod
    def apply_offset(indices, index_size, k):
    
        sample_size = len(indices)

        # Create offset tensor
        offset = tf.range(k, dtype=np.int32) * index_size
        
        offset = tf.repeat(offset, sample_size)
        
        # Apply offset to indices
        transformed_indices = tf.tile(indices, [k]) + offset
        
        return transformed_indices
    


    @tf.function
    def call(self, node_states, edge_states_k, all_edge_indices, states_graph_ids, num_graphs, training=False):

        # Define the forward pass
        node_hidden_states = tf.tile(node_states, [num_graphs, 1])

        indices_first = self.apply_offset(all_edge_indices[:,0], len(node_states), num_graphs)
        indices_second = self.apply_offset(all_edge_indices[:,1], len(node_states), num_graphs)

        # Execute T times
        for _ in range(self.hparams['T']):
            # We have the combination of the hidden states of the main nodes with the neighbours
            mainNodes = tf.gather(node_hidden_states, indices_first)
            neighNodes = tf.gather(node_hidden_states, indices_second)

            # We select the edge states of each interaction between nodes
            

            #input.shape = (nodes_first.length, node_state_dim + node_state_dim + link_state_dim)
            #Each row represents a pair of nodes through which the message will be sent (i -> j) (=batch),
            # and the columns represent the concat of node i state, node j state, and the edge states.
            input = tf.concat([mainNodes, neighNodes, edge_states_k], axis=1)


            outputs = self.Message(input)

            #print(outputs)

            #Sums the received messages
            ### 1.b Sum of output values according to link id index
            nodes_inputs_first = tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum(data=outputs, segment_ids=indices_first,
                                                        num_segments=len(node_states)*num_graphs)
            nodes_inputs_second = tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum(data=outputs, segment_ids=indices_second,
                                                        num_segments=len(node_states)*num_graphs)
            nodes_inputs = nodes_inputs_first + nodes_inputs_second

            ### 2. Update for each link
            # GRUcell needs a 3D tensor as state because there is a matmul: Wrap the link state
            outputs, node_state_list = self.Update(nodes_inputs, [node_hidden_states])


            #The state of each edge is updated
            node_hidden_states = node_state_list[0]

        # Perform sum of all hidden states and passed to the readout function
        nodes_combi_outputs = tf.math.segment_sum(node_hidden_states, states_graph_ids, name=None)

        r = self.Readout(nodes_combi_outputs,training=training)
        return r


As far as I understand, the error is caused because the shape of node_hidden_states is 0, but I don't know why this is possible.
What I tried is debugging the code in VSCode and wait for the exception to happen. When I got the exception, I used the debug console to recall the neural network with the same input, but surprisingly I do not caught any exception.
I'm trying to analize the code but I don't know what may be causing node_hidden_states to have shape [0].
Please any help would be very much appreciated. It is my first post, so if I've commited any mistake I apologize in advance.
